# error en vs code (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio

arraque hoy a programar con python en Vs Code y cuando le doy al boton de la esquina superior derecha "run python file" me sale ese error en la terminal. El problema es solo cuando uso dicho boton, si lo corro desde la terminal no tiene problema. Y no encuentro como solucionarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está mal configurado el entorno. La ruta del ejecutable de python tiene un caracter `}` que no parece ir allí, en `c:/users/admin}/bla/bla`. Si ese es tu usuario, sugiero probar con otro que no tenga caracteres especiales.

Comment: gracias genio!! me re ayudo!!